# Issues connecting to mysql, random database connection errors,

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-connect

I'm currently hosting a Wordpress site on windows azure and keep getting random connect issues.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): An operation on a socket could 
not be performed because the  system      lacked sufficient 
buffer space or because a queue was full. 
in  D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1372
```

Any idea? help will greatly be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked the drive space?  I'm guessing if you've 100% usage windows might not allow creation of a socket file.

Answer (score 0):

As referred to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx)

This error message, which is associated with the Winsock error WSAENOBUFS and actually comes from Windows rather than SQL Server directly, has two well-understood root causes. However, it still stumps people today, probably because  there is no single source which explains both root causes and offers solutions for both. Here is a description of the two common situations where you may see this error and quick solutions for each:

```
 1. OS runs out of memory for TCP buffers
 2. OS runs out of available TCP “ephemeral” ports
```